# Map disappear on yours installation <help>

Tags: navigation, openstreetmap

I want to install YOURS on my own map,i get reference from http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/YOURS

so this is my step:

1.checkout from repository
2.copy yours into my htmlRootFolder

But when i access it with www.domain.com/yours there is not map appear on it,

How to solve this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

oh. actually i have wrong in source code.I should checkout from http://svn.openstreetmap.org/applicatio … on-1.0-via 
Ok, this is step by step which i did to install YOURS

1. i following reference from http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/YOURS and checkout from http://svn.openstreetmap.org/applicatio … on-1.0-via
2. i checkout gosmore source from http://svn.openstreetmap.org/applicatio … ng/gosmore
3. rebuild my file planet.osm.bz2 use gosmore with command : bzcat country.osm.bz2 | ./gosmore rebuild 
   output is default.pak file
4. i put YOURS/* to /var/www so i can acces it via browser with http://localhost
   now i can access map, but when i make a route from one location to another location and click find route, error message :Status: An unexpected error occured in Gosmore: appear

i check on /var/log/apache2/error.log and i get this error message :

```
 [Thu Dec 22 13:18:01 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: format in /home/maple/yours/api/1.0/gosmore.php on line 105, referer: http://localhost/

[Thu Dec 22 13:18:01 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Warning:  fopen(/home/maple/yours/commands.log): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/maple/yours/api/1.0/gosmore.php on line 140, referer: http://localhost/

[Thu Dec 22 13:18:01 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Warning:  chdir(): No such file or directory (errno 2) in /home/maple/yours/api/1.0/gosmore.php on line 146, referer: http://localhost/
nice: ./gosmore: No such file or directory

[Thu Dec 22 13:18:01 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Warning:  fopen(/home/maple/yours/requests.csv): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/maple/yours/api/1.0/gosmore.php on line 235, referer: http://localhost/

[Thu Dec 22 13:18:01 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Warning:  fopen(/home/maple/yours/requests.csv): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/maple/yours/api/1.0/gosmore.php on line 242, referer: http://localhost/
```

What should i do to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, i have create these folder manually, then i have modify some php file.

I have post that on [http://forum.openstreetmap.org/viewtopic.php?id=14819](http://forum.openstreetmap.org/viewtopic.php?id=148190)

Thanks All